# Calculate distance matrix for 3D points

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance, euclidean-distance

I have the lists xA, yA, zA and the lists xB, yB, zB in Matlab. The contain the the x,y and z coordinates of points of type A and type B. There may be different numbers of type A and type B points.

I would like to calculate a matrix containing the Euclidean distances between points of type A and type B. Of course, I only need to calculate one half of the matrix, since the other half contains duplicate data.

What is the most efficient way to do that?

When I'm done with that, I want to find the points of type B that are closest to one point of type A. How do I then find the coordinates the closest, second closest, third closest and so on points of type B?

Comment: For pairwise distances between two different sets of points you need to compute the whole matrix and not half the matrix. That consideration only applies when you compute pairwise distances between all the points in one set of points (and you can use [`pdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) for that case).

Comment: Just for precision of language: MATLAB doesn’t have lists, everything is an array. `xA` etc. can be either 1xN or Nx1 arrays, it would be good if you would specify which it is, and, ideally, you would provide example data. That would help answers like below to show you how to convert your data, rather than starting with “Given a matrix A of size [N,3]”, which you don’t have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a matrix `A` of size `[N,3]` and a matrix `B` of size `[M,3]`, you can use the [pdist2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) function to get a matrix of size `[M,N]` containing all the pairwise distances.

If you want to order the points from `B` by their distance to the `r`th point in `A` then you can sort the `r`th row of the pairwise distance matrix.

```matlab
% generate some example data
N = 4
M = 7

A = randn(N,3)
B = randn(M,3)

% compute N x M matrix containing pairwise distances
D = pdist2(A, B, 'euclidean')

% sort points in B by their distance to the rth point in A
r = 3
[~, b_idx] = sort(D(r,:))
```

Then `b_idx` will contain the *indices* of the points in `B` sorted by their distance to the `r`th point in `A`. So the actual points in `B` ordered by `b_idx` can be obtained with `B(b_idx,:)`, which has the same size as `B`.

If you want to do this for all `r` you could use

```matlab
[~, B_idx] = sort(D, 1)
```

to sort all the rows of `D` at the same time. Then the `r`th row of `B_idx` will contain `b_idx`.

---

If your only objective is to find the closest `k` points in `B` for each point in `A` (for some positive integer `k` which is less than `M`), then we would *not* generally want to compute all the pairwise distances. This is because space-partitioning data structures like [K-D-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) can be used to improve the efficiency of searching without explicitly computing all the pairwise distances.

Matlab provides a [`knnsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) function that uses K-D-trees for this exact purpose. For example, if we do

```matlab
k = 2
B_kidx = knnsearch(B, A, 'K', k)
```

then `B_kidx` will be the first two columns of `B_idx`, i.e. for each point in `A` the indices of the nearest two points in `B`. Also, note that this is only going to be more efficient than the `pdist2` method when `k` is relatively small. If `k` is too large then `knnsearch` will automatically use the explicit method from before instead of the K-D-tree approach.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. knnsearch sounds very interesting. How would I apply that to three-dimensional coordinates?

Comment: I added some more information to the end of the `knnsearch` discussion at the end of the answer.

Comment: Many thanks again. That really help a lot. :-)